# Django global, application-wide variables

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I am trying to set up global variables that would be accessible by any of the threads in Django. I know there are endless posts on stackoverflow about this, and everyone says don't do it. I am writing a web application which does some file processing using the [Acora](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/acora) Python module.  The Acora module builds a tree of sorts based on some input data (strings). The process of building the tree takes some time, so I'd like to build the Acora structure at application start up time, so that when files are submitted to be processed, the Acora structures would be ready to go. This would shave 30 seconds from each file to be processed if I could pull this off.

I've tried a few methods, but for each request, the data isn't available and I think it's because each request is processed in a separate thread, so I need a cross thread or shared memory solution, or I have to find something other than Acora. Also, Acora can't be pickled or serialized as it is a C module and doesn't expose it's data to Python. I've tried Django cache and cPickle, without luck because they use Pickle.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Pull the Acora task out of Django entirely. Use Twisted or some other event framework to create a service that Django can talk to either directly or via a message queue such as Celery whenever it has files that need processing.